# Why I'm getting 0 latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, location-provider

I have 3 fragment class in tab layout and in one of them I have implemented a button to get the current location(latitude & longitude). Everything works fine except the latitude and longitude showing value 0.

```
    package com.swipetab.example;

        import java.util.Calendar;

        import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
        import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.TimePicker;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
            Button Date, Time, GpsBtn;
            GPSTracker gps;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container,
                        false);
                Date = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                Time = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
                GpsBtn = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
                Date.setOnClickListener(DateOnClickListener);
                Time.setOnClickListener(TimeOnClickListener);
                GpsBtn.setOnClickListener(GPSOnClickListener);

                return myFragmentView;
            }

            OnClickListener DateOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    showDatePicker();

                }
            };

            OnClickListener TimeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    showTimePicker();

                }
            };
            OnClickListener GPSOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    showGPSLocation();

                }
            };

            private void showDatePicker() {
                DatePicker date = new DatePicker();
                /**
                 * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
                 */
                Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                date.setArguments(args);
                /**
                 * Set Call back to capture selected date
                 */
                date.setCallBack(ondate);

                date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
            }

            private void showTimePicker() {
                Time time = new Time();
                /**
                 * Set Up Current Time Into dialog
                 */
                Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("hour", calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                args.putInt("min", calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                time.setArguments(args);
                /**
                 * Set Call back to capture selected date
                 */
                time.setCallBack(ontime);

                time.show(getFragmentManager(), "Time Picker");
            }

            private void showGPSLocation() {
                gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();

                }
            }

            OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker arg0, int year,
                        int month, int day) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String TabOfFragmentB = ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                            .getTabFragmentB();

                    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                    TabOfFragmentB);

                    String y = Integer.toString(year);
                    String m = Integer.toString(month);
                    String d = Integer.toString(day);

                    String dat = y.concat("-") + m.concat("-") + d;

                    fragmentB.b_updateDate(dat);

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-"
                                    + String.valueOf(day), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            OnTimeSetListener ontime = new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker arg0, int hourOfDay, int min) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String TabOfFragmentB = ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                            .getTabFragmentB();

                    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                    TabOfFragmentB);
                    int hour;
                    String am_pm;
                    if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                        hour = hourOfDay - 12;
                        am_pm = "PM";
                    } else {
                        hour = hourOfDay;
                        am_pm = "AM";
                    }
                    String h = Integer.toString(hour);
                    String m = Integer.toString(min);

                    String t = h.concat(":") + m + " " + am_pm;

                    fragmentB.b_updateTime(t);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            String.valueOf(hour) + "-" + String.valueOf(min),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
        }
```

GPSTracker class

```
    package com.swipetab.example;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final Context mContext;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

        // flag for GPS status
        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location location; // location
        double latitude; // latitude
        double longitude; // longitude

        // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

        // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        // Declaring a Location Manager
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracker(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            getLocation();
        }

        private Location getLocation() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                    System.out.println("Please Enable!!");
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }

        /**
         * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
         * app
         * */
        public void stopUsingGPS() {
            if (locationManager != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Function to get latitude
         * */
        public double getLatitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            // return latitude
            return latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to get longitude
         * */
        public double getLongitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            // return longitude
            return longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
         * 
         * @return boolean
         * */
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        /**
         * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
         * lauch Settings Options
         * */
        public void showSettingsAlert() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog
                    .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

            // On pressing Settings button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            // on pressing cancel button
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if conditions, are the problems i think.if GPS is not enable then you fetch the location from network provider and for network provider your option ->(use wireless network )should be enable in location service settings and your internet connection should be working.and for basic working please find the link.[enter link description here](http://javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: it's ACCESS_CO(A)RSE_LOCATION instead of ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

You can change the coordinates using the monitor control in android studio. You must go to Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor. It show a windows, in this windows, you choose Emulator Control, in the bottom you can change the coordinates (longitude, altitude)

Comment: There, you can send the emulator longitude and altitude